# Proxy disabled, but SBT still does not download dependencies

Tags: playframework, sbt

I installed Typesafe Activator (including SBT) and started it with "activator ui". Unfortunately, it can't even download the first dependency (jansi-1.11). The logs say:

```
[...]
trying https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.pom
  tried https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.pom
  ERROR: Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/fusesource/jansi/jansi/1.11/jansi-1.11.pom
[...]
```

I can, of course, provide the full logs, if needed.

I found a lot of similar problems, mostly related to proxy issues. I'm trying to access the repository from a workplace environment indeed, but the sysadmin disabled the (Kerberos) proxy for my IP. I can now copy and past the jcenter...-URL into a browser and the browser access the pom-file. Unfortunately, SBT can't :-(

This is my setup:

- Windows 7 (64-bit)
- Oracle Java 8 JDK Build 65 (64-bit)
- (Java 7 is also installed, but JAVA_HOME and PATH point to Java 8)
- Typesafe Activator 1.3.7 (including SBT 0.13.9)

Before I tested, I deleted the .sbt, .activator and .ivy2 directories. I tried both the minimal and the full activator distribution. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your network traffic will still be going out from your corporate network to the www via a proxy server though right?

If the proxy is disabled, then can you browse the www while connected to the corporate network or are you connecting to an ISP via a wifi router or something.

If you're requests to bintray are still via a proxy then you need to setup  some additional configuration. Did you try configuring the activator config file, found in your user home directory under ~/.activator/activatorconfig.txt. Note that this file may not exist so you may need to create it and enter the following:

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=YOUR PROXY HOST HERE
-Dhttp.proxyPort=YOUR PROXY PORT HERE
-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts="localhost|127.0.0.1"

# If you need to authenticate with the proxy use the below
#-Dhttp.proxyUser=YOUR PROXY USER HERE
#-Dhttp.proxyPassword=YOUR PROXY PASSWORD HERE
```

Comment: Thank you. It works! I thought I would completely bypass the proxy. However, as you suggested, my traffic still went through the proxy. I entered proxyHost and -Port for both http and https in the activatorconfig.txt as well as jvmargs in .sbt and now everything works like a charm. (I did not entered the nonProxyHosts, becaus I think what you suggest here are the default values.)

Comment: Glad you got it working Barret. If you think this is a correct answer for you then you could flag that this answered your question (by checking the tick mark) to save others from adding more answers.